# React DND dropping incorrect element

Tags: javascript, reactjs, drag-and-drop, react-dnd

I am trying to create a simple drag and drop using React-DND.
In the DragDrop Component there are 4 blocks created onload as default state.
I am trying to drag these to 2 boards and also remove the element from the blockList.
My issue is that it seems to be using the items index rather than the id property.
When I drag item 1 and then drag item 2 it drops item 1 again because the index has shifted. I want to drop the item I am dragging not the index of that item.

I am passing the id to the drag component

```
const [{ collected, isDragging }, drag] = useDrag(() => ({
        type: ItemTypes.BLOCK,
        item: {
            id: id
        },
        collect: (monitor) => ({
            isDragging: !!monitor.isDragging(),
        })

    }))
```

Also accessing it in the drop hook

```
const [{ isOver }, drop] = useDrop(() => ({
        accept: ItemTypes.BLOCK,
        drop: (item) => addBlockToBoard(item.id, item.name),
        collect: (monitor) => ({
            isOver: !!monitor.isOver(),
        })
    }))
    //console.log("isOver: ", isOver);
    const addBlockToBoard = (id, name) => {
        const currentBlock = blockList.find(block => block.id === id);
        //console.log("Current: ", currentBlock);
        setBoard((board) => [...board, currentBlock]);
        setAbove((board) => [...board, currentBlock]);
        updateBlockList(currentBlock);
        //setBlocklist((blockList) => [...remainingBlocks])
    }
```

I have a sandbox of the full code here:
https://codesandbox.io/s/jolly-napier-ipyg86?file=/src/BelowBoard.js

After mapping the items to the blockList how does react dnd know what the data is for the draggable object?

Thanks in advance. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Hello i solve the problem change the key value of Block comp. as you see below
Probably there is a problem in library or it works as properly anyway, library should reinitialize the draggable items when item list change.

https://codesandbox.io/p/sandbox/restless-rgb-m7zny8

```
<div className="blocks">
  {blockList.map((item, i) => {
    return (
      <Block
        id={item.id}
        url={item.url}
        data-id={item.id}
        key={`block-${item.id}`} <---- SOLUTION
        // key={`block-${i}`
      />
    );
  })}
</div>
```